# Flightgear: ILS makes my aircraft - Cessna 337 - turn away from the airport

Tags: flightgear

In FlightGear, all manual ILS approaches work like a charm.

But many ILS approaches on autopilot are bonkers.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Approach Basel-Mulhouse (LFSB) from Mulhouse-Habsheim airport (LFGB).
2. Hit `F12` for the radio/comms menu and select the ILS frequency for the RWY 15 approach, 111.55 MHz.
3. Hit `F11` for the autopilot menu, and push in the dial ("Pulled Out" is unselected), and select `NAV` and `ALT`.
4. Depart and fly a course of 150 degrees magnetic. Line up with the ILS, intercept the glide slope, and select `AP ON` in the autopilot menu.
5. The aircraft turns away north-east.

[image: Flight path when approaching runway 15]

**One ILS approach that works:**

1. Depart from LSPD, and fly due east. Align with the RWY 33 ILS of Basel-Mulhouse. The frequency is 109.35.
2. In the autopilot menu, repeat the same steps.
3. The autopilot flies the plane to the runway.

This is very annoying, as I don't know which ILS approach will work and which one won't.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to tag my question with "flightgear", so I chose another flight simulator.